# How to see logs for gmail addon which is deployed to marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-addons

I have created a gmail addon and deployed a version of it to our domain marketplace. After first screen i am not able to navigate to my next screen. I think there are some permissions which i need to enable.

I am using **admin directory api** in my application. i have enabled admin sdk access to my app from console.

How can i find logs for the app that is deployed to marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your Apps Script code in try/catch blocks and use the console API to log errors and warnings.

Then visit the StackDriver Logging dashboard associated with your project to view information logged into the console.

To view the logs, open the Script Editor, go to View > StackDriver.

[image]

Comment: I have seen that but in that logs format is different. 
 log name is -> "projects/my_app/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" . But i am not able to see logs which i kept in my code. Can you . help me with this?